# 404 error when calling api in laravel 6.4 with apache2 virtualhost

Tags: laravel, api, apache2, http-status-code-404, virtualhost

I have Laravel 6.4 installed on ubuntu 18.04 with php 7.2 and apache2. I have built a case study to develop an api and when I execute the *php artisan serve* command and use *postman* to do the query everything works fine. But if I create a virtualhost, I can see the website without problems, however, when executing a query through the postman I get the 404 error.
The .htaccess file is the one that brings by default laravel:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and my virtualhost is the following:

```
<VirtualHost test-api.local:80>
    ServerName test-api.local

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/restlav/public
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test-api.local-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test-api.local-access.log combined

    <Directory "/var/www/html/restlav">
            Options +FollowSymLinks
            RewriteEngine On
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have already tried to make the changes that are suggested in the official documentation and nothing. The rewrite module is enabled. If anyone could help me I appreciate it in advance.

Comment: AllowOverride all

Answer (score 2):

In the <Directory> section you need to set AllowOverride to All:

```
<VirtualHost test-api.local:80>
    ServerName test-api.local

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/restlav/public
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test-api.local-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test-api.local-access.log combined

    <Directory "/var/www/html/restlav">
            Options +FollowSymLinks
            RewriteEngine On
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also make sure to enable the rewrite module in the apache server:

```
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

And don't forget to finally restart the apache server to make the changes come into effect:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart apache2
```